# ASP .NET MVC-3 route add/map to a virtual directory for an alias

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have followed [Maarten Balliauw's post](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx) on domain routing. I had been able route to controller's for different sub-domains. But I don't know how to route to a virtual directory. As you see this is a sample example for routing to usual mvc controllers,

```
routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute( 
        "home.example.com", // Domain with parameters 
        "{action}/{id}",    // URL with parameters 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults 
));
```

As my blog resides on Virtual Directory I need to add the route to this virtual directory named "~/blog"
I have tried code like this with no good result,

```
        routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute(
            "blog.domain.com",                                     // Domain with parameters
            "blog",                                        // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "blog" }  // Parameter defaults
        ));
```

If anyone can bring some light into this it will be amazing.

Comment: Is the virtual directory always blog? The virtual directory is part of the URL so possibly blog/{action}/{id}

Comment: It didn't work out.Let me clarify. It's a virtual directory on shared windows hosting. It's not part of main site which is hosted on the root of the domain.

Comment: What is the behavior if you don't specify the domain? IIS will leave the request in your mvc application and you can start from there. I think there may be some other issues that are making it not work, but it doesn't seem to need domain routes.

Comment: Oh, I understood the question. Now I understand something more :). So, the blog is in a different virtual directory than the home?

Comment: Sorry guyz. My apologies. Now, I have been able to create sub-domain which points to a site with the help of my hosting provider. In that case no need to do domain route. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to make the blog an MVC Area of your main web application.  You create a new Area called blog.  This creates a Folder called "Areas/blog" in your main webroot.  You can then turn the 'blog' folder into a virtual directory pointing to your blog application.

I did this in a recent web project for my admin backend.  I used this blog post and it worked great.  Very simple and keeps your application nice and clean.

http://bob.archer.net/content/aspnet-mvc3-areas-separate-projects

When you are actually inside the 'blog' area your actionlinks and everything works like normal.  You only need to add "Area = 'blog'" to your links that move you from area to area.

Once you create the blog area take a look at the routes file it creates.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: I'm giving you bounty as it expires soon.. though couldn't complete the compile still now.. lots of errors in BlogEngine .Net blog directory.. saying "namespace resource is not found"

Comment: I don't have any experience in using BlogEngine.Net, so not able to give you any input in that regard.  I hope you are able to figure it out.  Maybe post some code from the errors and I'll see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The implication here is that the virtual folder is completely distinct from the MVC application it's within -- if that's the case, do you need to use the MVC routing at all, since you don't need any of the MVC resources to begin with?  It would probably be easier just to configure the subdomain to point at the appropriate folder within IIS, and bypass MVC's routing altogether.

Comment: The hosting provider doesn't allow creating sub-domains like that. I can only create aliases.